# jQuery preventDefault onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple jQuery script that asks to confirm action when you click on a link. And it works great when it's a normal `a href` link, but I have `onclick` script assigned to the button and it does not prevent it from firing. I need it to prevent it only once. How can I achieve that?

```js
$(".mybutton").one('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).html("Are you sure?");   
});

function test() {
  $(".forthebutton").html("button click function worked");  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="mybutton" onclick="test();">Button</button>

<br /><br /><br />

<span class="forthebutton">button click should change this text</span>
```

Comment: On clicking the button, you are intending to change both the text in the span with class "forthebutton" and also ask confirmation? Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove original `onclick` and give it back in this case because you can't influent on `onclick` handler.

```js
const btn = $(".mybutton");
const onclick = btn.prop('onclick'); // save onclick fn

btn.prop('onclick', null); // remove onclick from button
btn.one('click', function() {
    $(this).html("Are you sure?");
    btn.on('click', onclick); // add onclick back to button
});

function test() {
  $(".forthebutton").html("button click function worked");  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="mybutton" onclick="test();">Button</button>

<br /><br /><br />

<span class="forthebutton">button click should change this text</span>
```